# At what point did Obi-Wan Kenobi know that Darth Vader was on board of Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Based on an assertion in the answer to: " [When Can the Dark Side Be Sensed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9174/when-can-the-dark-side-be-sensed/9175#9175) ":

Is there some canon (ideally, G-canon but not required) information clearly indicating whether Obi-Wan Kenobi know that Darth Vader was on board of Death Star before they actually physically bumped into each other?

If earlier, just when did he find out?

**UPDATE**: To clarify, "Vader knew when he discussed it with Tarkin" is NOT evidence for or against, unless there's a canon proof that Obi-Wan must have detected Vader at the same time as Vader detected Obi-Wan

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel)) for *Star Wars: A New Hope* (listed as having been authored by George Lucas but famously ghost-written by Alan Dean Foster) places Obi-Wan's sensing of Vader's presence much later on than Vader's conversation with Tarkin:

> Kenobi had avoided one patrol after another, slowly working his way
>   back toward the docking bay holding the freighter. Just another two
>   turns and he should be at the hangar. What he would do then would be
>   determined by how inconspicuous his charges had been.

a few minutes later

> **Ben sensed something directly ahead and slowed cautiously. It had a
>   most familiar feel to it, a half-remembered mental odor he could not
>   quite place. Then the figure stepped out in front of him, blocking his
>   entry to the hangar not five meters away. The outline and size of the
>   figure completed the momentary puzzle. It was the maturity of the mind
>   he had sensed that had temporarily confused him. His hand moved
>   naturally to the hilt of his deactivated saber.**

Although Kenobi may have *subconsciously* suspected something was wrong (his insistence on Luke staying behind, the fact that he repeatedly checks his lightsaber, etc) he doesn't consciously realise that it's Anakin/Vader until he practically falls over him.

Comment: "Mental odor"? "What an incredible new smell you've discovered!"

Comment: @DVK - You asked for a G-Canon answer, and you shall have one...

Comment: anakin's mental odor - smells like burnt popcorn probably

Comment: @NKCampbell - New car smell, I assumed.

Comment: @NKCampbell: Sand.

Answer (score 15):

The first time Vader felt Obi-Wan's presence was shortly after the Millennium Falcon landed. From The [*Star Wars: A New Hope* script](https://web.archive.org/web/20120111205014/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/anh-script.shtml)

> VADER: Send a scanning crew on board. I want every part of this ship
>   checked.
>   OFFICER: Yes, sir.
>   VADER: I sense something...a presence I haven't felt since...
>   Vader turns quickly and exits the hangar.

We could assume Obi-Wan also felt his presence at this time, but he said nothing about it. He made his plan and later, Vader sensed **his intentions.** Just after Luke and Han made Leia out of her Cell, Vader had this discussion with Tarkin.

Also from The [*Star Wars: A New Hope* script](https://web.archive.org/web/20120111205014/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/anh-script.shtml)

> VADER: Obi-Wan is here. The Force is with him.
>   TARKIN: If you're right, he must not be allowed to escape.
>   VADER: **Escape is not his plan.** I must face him alone.

So, Obi-Wan must be aware of Vader's presence before that because he felt that **Obi-Wan planned his duel with him**. To plan this duel, Obi-Wan must be aware of the presence of his apprentice.

Comment: "Obi-Wan must be aware of Vader's presence much before that." - can you explain why? If you look at the linked question, it's specifically postulated that Vader may have known WAY before Obi-Wan. That was precisely the point of my question.

Comment: Obi-Wan couldn't plan to duel Vader if he didn't know he was there.

Comment: Fair enough. +1 and accept

Comment: @dvk - Escape isn't his plan. He's busily sabotaging the station at this point.