# In Star Wars, does Yoda become more or less powerful with age?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Okay so listen to this example.  In Attack of the Clones, when Yoda was battling Dooku, Dooku crushed the bottom of that large pipe structure to make it fall on Obi-Wan and Anakin.  Yoda then used the force to stop it.  In this scene it looked like Yoda struggled to lift it with two hands.

Now fast forward (or rewind if your going by when they were released) to The Empire Strikes Back where Yoda uses the force to get Luke's X-wing out of the swamp.  Now, ignoring how this was a puppet and episode II was CGI, Yoda in episode V seemed to somewhat "effortlessly" pull his fighter out with one hand.

Based on these observations I assume that a jedi becomes stronger with the force over time.

But then look at skills with the lightsaber.  Same example, Yoda fighting Dooku, and Yoda on Dagobah. Episode II/III Yoda had some serious skills, but Yoda on Dagobah could hardly move (again, ignoring the fact that he was a puppet so his movement looked a little stiff).

On the same subject of lightsaber skill, do you think young Yoda was even better with a lightsaber than what he showed in II and III?

Also, does this mean young Yoda was more powerful than old Yoda?  Like if young Yoda was to battle Darth Sidious in III, would he have won?

Comment: See also [Does the Force wane as you age?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141321/70236)

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate.